# Using docker-compose with CI - how to deal with exit codes and daemonized linked containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Right now our Jenkins agents generate a docker-compose.yml for each of our Rails projects and then run docker-compose up. The docker-compose.yml has a main "web" container that has rbenv and all of our other Rails dependencies inside. It is linked to a DB container that contains the test Postgres DB.

The problem comes when we need to actually run the tests and generate exit codes. Our CI server will only deploy if the test script returns exit 0, but docker-compose always returns 0, even if one of the container commands fail.

The other issue is that the DB container runs indefinitely, even after the web container is done running the tests, so `docker-compose up` never returns.

Is there a way we can use docker-compose for this process? We would need to be able to run the containers, but exit after the web container is complete and return it's exit code. Right now we are stuck manually using docker to spin up the DB container and run the web container with the --link option.

Answer (score 105):

Since version `1.12.0`, you can use the `--exit-code-from` option.

From [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/):

> --exit-code-from SERVICE
>
> Return the exit code of the selected service container. Implies --abort-on-container-exit.

Comment: That should be the right way of doing it if you are using ```docker-compose``` 1.12.0 and above. Maybe it is your case too. An example could be: ```docker-compose up --exit-code-from test-unit```. Note that it didn't work for me until I added a ```set -e``` at the beginning of my script.

Comment: `--exit-code-from` doesn't work with `-d` though. It will throw these errors: `using --exit-code-from implies --abort-on-container-exit` and  `--abort-on-container-exit and -d cannot be combined.`

Comment: I was able to get this working on Travis CI: https://travis-ci.org/coyote-team/coyote/builds/274582053

here's the travis.yml: https://github.com/coyote-team/coyote/blob/master/.travis.yml#L12

Comment: the documentation is atrocious. what flags is this compatible with? is it only one service or can you pass it several?

Comment: Note that these args apply to [docker-compose up](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) and not [docker-compose run](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/)

Comment: note that to run only certain service u should use command `set -e; docker-compose -f file up --exit-code-from service service`

Comment: This is a correct answer but I got error code 0 at any cases. then I realized that "restart: unless-stopped" was my fault. I changed it to "restart: no" then my container returns the real --exit-code-from SERVICE afterwards.

Comment: if your service contains more than 1 replica, then this unfortunately doesn't work. It captures the exit code of the first container of the service to exit and returns it, while forcefully stopping the other as well (due to implied `--abort-on-container-exit`). What worked for me was @kojiro 's answer modified to list all containers for a service (`-a` flag along with service name)

Answer (score 50):

`docker-compose run` is the simple way to get the exit statuses you desire. For example:

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml 
roit:
    image: busybox
    command: 'true'
naw:
    image: busybox
    command: 'false'
$ docker-compose run --rm roit; echo $?
Removing test_roit_run_1...
0
$ docker-compose run --rm naw; echo $?
Removing test_naw_run_1...
1
```

Alternatively, you do have the option to [inspect](http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#inspect) the dead containers. You can use the `-f` flag to get just the exit status.

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating test_naw_1...
Creating test_roit_1...
Attaching to test_roit_1
test_roit_1 exited with code 0
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
$ docker-compose ps -q | xargs docker inspect -f '{{ .Name }} exited with status {{ .State.ExitCode }}'
/test_naw_1 exited with status 1
/test_roit_1 exited with status 0
```

As for the db container that never returns, if you use `docker-compose up` then you will need to sigkill that container; that's probably not what you want. Instead, you can use `docker-compose up -d` to run your containers daemonized, and manually kill the containers when your test is complete. `docker-compose run` *should* run linked containers for you, but I have heard chatter on SO about a bug preventing that from working as intended right now.

Comment: The problem with docker run is that it does not give any output when run with -T, and we want the output so we can inspect failed builds.

Comment: @LoganSerman you can inspect the output with `docker-compose logs`

Comment: Is there a way to constantly pipe those logs to STDOUT during the run so we can see it while the CI build is in progress?

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you are running with `-T`

Comment: Some of the commands we run inside of the container to run tests have the potential to ask for input, we want to run with -T to avoid this. Rbenv for example asks if you want to reinstall a Ruby version if it already exists.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, works like a charm!

Answer (score 28):

Building on kojiro's answer:

`docker-compose ps -q | xargs docker inspect -f '{{ .State.ExitCode }}' | grep -v '^0' | wc -l | tr -d ' '`

1. get container IDs
2. get last runs exit code for each container ID
3. only status codes that does not start with '0'
4. count number of non-0 status codes
5. trim out white space

Returns how many non-0 exit codes were returned. Would be 0 if everything exited with code 0.

Comment: You can also use the non-quiet output from `docker-compose ps`, for example: `docker-compose ps | grep -c "Exit 1"` will give you the count where "Exit 1" is matched in the display from `docker-compose ps` (which provides a pretty-printed summary table of results).  The exit codes are listed in the "State" column.

Comment: This is really awesome. In my case failing test suite running in containers don't make the containers exit with a code of 1. I can't aggregate if any exited with a code of 1 since none of them do.... Any idea how to handle this case?

Comment: if you are trying to get exited containers, you also need to include `-a` flag to `ps` otherwise they are not listed

Answer (score 17):

Use `docker wait` to get the exit code:

```
$ docker-compose -p foo up -d
$ ret=$(docker wait foo_bar_1)
```

`foo` is the "project name".   In the example above, I specified it explicitly, but if you don't supply it, it's the directory name.   `bar` is the name you give to the system under test in your docker-compose.yml.

Note that `docker logs -f` does the right thing, too, exiting when the container stops.   So you can put

```
$ docker logs -f foo_bar_1
```

between the `docker-compose up` and the `docker wait` so you can watch your tests run.

Comment: thank you for this idea. I use it as exit code for GitLab step :)

Answer (score 16):

`--exit-code-from SERVICE` and `--abort-on-container-exit` don't work in scenarios where you need to run all containers to completion, but fail if one of them exited early. An example might be if running 2 test suits in concurrently in different containers.

With @spenthil's suggestion, you can wrap `docker-compose` in a script that will fail if any containers do.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Wrap docker-compose and return a non-zero exit code if any containers failed.

docker-compose "$@"

exit $(docker-compose -f docker-compose.ci.build.yml ps -q | tr -d '[:space:]' |
  xargs docker inspect -f '{{ .State.ExitCode }}' | grep -v 0 | wc -l | tr -d '[:space:]')
```

Then on your CI server simply change `docker-compose up` to `./docker-compose.sh up`.

Comment: this script never reaches the exit section as other containers (such as databases, web apps) run perpetually.  running in detached mode it exits as soon as the container are up

Comment: That's right, this only works if you want to run _all_ containers to completion. Probably not particularly common, but it was useful for me at the time of writing and I thought I would share it.

Comment: Upvoted your answer anyway as it got me most of the way there!  Adding Docker wait on each test container in detached mode got it working.  Thanks for sharing:)

Answer (score 11):

If you're willing to use `docker-compose run` to manually kick off your tests, adding the `--rm` flag, oddly enough, causes Compose to accurately reflect your command's exit status.

Here's my example:

```
$ docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.7.0, build 0d7bf73

$ (docker-compose run bash false) || echo 'Test failed!'  # False negative.

$ (docker-compose run --rm bash false) || echo 'Test failed!'  # True positive.
Test failed!

$ (docker-compose run --rm bash true) || echo 'Test failed!'  # True negative.
```

Comment: Or `(docker-compose run --rm ...) || exit $?` for termination in case of error. Useful in bash scripts.

Answer (score 2):

[docker-rails](https://github.com/alienfast/docker-rails) allows you to specify which container's error code is returned to the main process, so you CI server can determine the result.  It is a great solution for CI and development for rails with docker.

For example

```
exit_code: web
```

in your `docker-rails.yml` will yield the `web` containers exit code as a result of the command `docker-rails ci test`.  `docker-rails.yml` is just a meta wrapper around the standard `docker-compose.yml` that gives you the potential to inherit/reuse the same base config for different environments i.e. development vs test vs parallel_tests.

Answer (score 2):

You can see exit status with:

```sh
echo $(docker-compose ps | grep "servicename" | awk '{print $4}')
```

Comment: Thanks for getting this started. Here's my version of this one (which works better for me b/c I think the command output format has changed since this answer was written) – `docker-compose ps | grep servicename | grep -v 'Exit 0' && echo "Automation or integration tests failed." && exit 1`

Answer (score 2):

In case you might run more docker-compose services with same name on one docker engine, and you don't know the exact name:

```
docker-compose up -d
(exit "${$(docker-compose logs -f test-chrome)##* }")
```

`echo %?` - returns exit code from test-chrome service

Benefits:

- wait's for exact service to exit
- uses service name, not container name

Answer (score 0):

If your service has more than one replica, then the solutions with `--exit-code-from` and `docker compose wait` won't work because they only use the exit code from the first service container to exit.

So what worked for me (for **docker compose v2**) to get the exit code of a multicontainer service is, (building on @kojiro 's and @spenthil 's responses):

```bash
docker compose ps -aq <SERVICE_NAME> | xargs docker inspect -f '{{ .State.ExitCode }}' | grep -v '^0' | wc -l | tr -d ' '
```

Note that if your docker compose is using multiple files to generate you should properly include them in the `ps` command as well, eg:
`docker compose -f docker-compose1.yml -f docker-compose2.yaml ps -aq <SERVICE_NAME>`