# How to stop all containers when one container stops with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Up until recently, when one was doing `docker-compose up` for a bunch of containers and one of the started containers stopped, all of the containers were stopped. This is not the case anymore since https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/741 and this is a really annoying for us: We use docker-compose to run selenium tests which means starting application server, starting selenium hub + nodes, starting tests driver, then exiting when tests driver stops.

Is there a way to get back old behaviour?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

You can use:

> docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit

Which will stop all containers if one of your containers stops

Comment: I'm not sure if this is _the_ way to do it, but it certainly works and even carries over the exit code of the stopped container. Pretty neat feature for integration tests.

Comment: Does not work in detached mode - "-d" though. Would love something like this so that if one container fails, Docker shuts down all its dependent containers as well.

Comment: To make sure the exit code corresponds with the exit code of the test container use the `--exit-code-from` command line option. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43367250/11567551 for details and links.

Answer (score 18):

In your docker compose file, setup your *test driver* container to depend on other containers (with `depends_on` parameter). Your docker compose file should look like this:

```
services:
  application_server:
     ...
  selenium:
     ...
  test_driver:
    entry_point: YOUR_TEST_COMMAND
    depends_on:
      - application_server
      - selenium
```

With dependencies expressed this way, run:

```
docker-compose run test_driver
```

and all the other containers will shut down when the `test_driver` container is finished.

This solution is an alternative to the `docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit` [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41841714/3937850). The latter will also shut down all other containers if any of them exits (not only the *test driver*). It depends on your use case which one is more adequate.

Comment: This suggested approach did not work for me. docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880f
docker-py version: 3.4.1
CPython version: 3.6.4
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018

Comment: Didn't work for me neither. The 'depends_on' containers are started before the main container starts, but they aren't stopped after the main container stops.

Comment: This works great for adhoc runs (i.e. tests. Yes it doesn't close other containers but for integration tests, the entire environment is discarded after running tests so that sort of cleanup doesn't matter. This [section](https://docs.docker.com/compose/faq/#whats-the-difference-between-up-run-and-start) on docker docs was helpful in explaining the difference between three

Answer (score 7):

Did you try the work around suggested on the link you provided?

Assuming your test script looked similar to this:

```
$ docker-compose rm -f
$ docker-compose build
$ docker-compose up --timeout 1 --no-build
```

When the application tests end, compose would exit and the tests finish.

In this case, with the new `docker-compose` version, change your test container to have a default no-op command (something like echo, or true), and change your test script as follows:

```
$ docker-compose rm -f
$ docker-compose build
$ docker-compose up --timeout 1 --no-build -d
$ docker-compose run tests test_command...
$ docker-compose stop
```

Using run allows you to get the exit status from the test run, and you only see the output of the tests (not all the dependencies).

[Reference](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/1754#issuecomment-154218084)

If this is not acceptable, you could refer to [Docker Remote API](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/reference/api/docker_remote_api/#docker-events) and watch for the `stop` event for the containers and act on it.

An example usage is this [docker-gen](https://github.com/jwilder/docker-gen) tool written in `golang` which [watches for container start events](https://github.com/jwilder/docker-gen/blob/d97a78b1c05a67f56b1ef1ffa8120c38ffac9447/docker-gen.go#L327), to automatically regenerate configuration files.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great tip. No, I did not try yet the suggested workaround and to be honest with you I read the link not carefully enough to understand I had a workaround in front of me! I will try that asap.

Comment: Another important thing to know: sadly the `docker-compose run foo` command doesn't set aliases of your `foo` service (docker-compose 1.8.0-rc1). See https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3492#issuecomment-230931596

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure this is the perfect answer to your problem, but [maestro](https://github.com/toscanini/maestro) for Docker, lets you manage mulitple Docker containers as single unit.

It should feel familiar as you group them using a YAML file.