# Is it possible to stop a docker container after other docker container inside the same network exits?

Tags: python, docker, selenium, docker-compose

I have three docker containers. First container is a Wordpress container which starts a wordpress instance. Second container is a selenium server container created from `selenium/standalone-chrome` image which is supposed to do some initial setup of the wordpress via UI interactions. I have a python script that has all the commands to send to the selenium server. I am running this script in a python container as the third container. All the containers are spawned using `docker-compose` and are in the same network, so that communication can happen.

Once the python container is finished running the script it exits, however the selenium server and the wordpress container keep running. Once I am done with the script, I want to stop the selenium server container as well but keep the wordpress container running.

I had a thought to run a script inside the python container as entrypoint which first executes the script and then issues a command to stop the other container but for that I guess the python container should also have docker available inside it. So, I think this will not work. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop all containers when one container stops with docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33799885/how-to-stop-all-containers-when-one-container-stops-with-docker-compose)

Comment: Editing the question for more details. I was not mentioning a third container which I want to keep running while only wanting to kill selenium container.

Comment: @NavjotSingh What's wrong with the third answer of the duplicate? Seems to cover your needs with some minor adjustments.

Comment: @super Just edited the question. I want to keep one of the containers alive, so essentially I don't want to stop everything.

Comment: @NavjotSingh My comment was in regards to your edit. The third answer shows an approach that would work for you. Just replace `docker-compose stop` with `docker-compose stop selenium`.

Comment: @super Wouldn't having a no op command as entry command instantly exit the container?

Comment: Yes, that's why you have a `docker-compose run` after it to run the container with the actual command you want.

Answer (score 0):

The command

`docker ps --filter=name='my-container'`

will show you if the interesting container is still here

example

`docker ps`

shows many containers

but you can filter

`docker ps --filter=name='cadvisor'                                                                                                                                     CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES 984f35929991        google/cadvisor              "/usr/bin/cadvisor -…"   3 years ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:1234->8080/tcp   cadvisor`
`

and so a script can test the presence of both containers, only one, and do a

`docker stop xxx`

when needed

Comment: I believe OP wants to make a sort of dependency so that all to happen automatically

Comment: maybe docker-compose events can do it, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events/#object-types

Comment: I will try to give it a shot. @AlexeyR. Yes I wanted the things to happen automatically.