# integration tests with docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, integration-testing

I have a rest api. I want to have a docker-compose setup that:

- starts the api server
- "waits" until it's up and running
- runs some api tests against the endpoints
- stops everything once the test job finished.

Now,

- The first part I can do.
- As for waiting for the backend to be up and runnning, as I understand it, `depends_on` does not quite cut it. the rest api does have a `/ping` endpoint tho in case we need it.
- struggling to find a minimal example online that:

  - uses volumes and does not explicitly copy tests files over.
  - runs the tests through a command in the docker file (as opposed to in the DockerFile)
  - again not sure if there is an idiomatic way of stopping everything after tests are done, but I did come across a somewhat related [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41841714/9199853) that suggests using `docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit`. is that the best way of achieving this?

currently my docker-compose file looks like this:

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'

networks:
  development:
    driver: bridge

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ../Dockerfile
    command: sbt run
    image: sbt
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "../:/root/build"
    networks:
      - development
  tests:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command: npm run test
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/tests/
      - /usr/tests/node_modules
    networks:
      - development
    depends_on:
      - app
```

and the node `Dockerfile` looking this:

```
FROM node:16

ADD package*.json /usr/tests/
ADD test.js /usr/tests/

WORKDIR /usr/tests/

RUN npm install
```

Full repo is here: https://github.com/ShahOdin/dockerise-everything/pull/1

Comment: Do the tests themselves need to run inside Docker, or do you just need something that can make HTTP requests to the published `ports:`?  That set of tasks seems a little beyond what Compose is capable of on its own, but if you had a test driver that ran outside of Docker it should be straightforward to script all of that (including starting and stopping the Compose stack).

Comment: ideally I'd like everything containerized. btw, I just realised I could have a request with retries and a timeout of say 10 sec calling the ping endpoint. so the waiting part is probably not too big of an issue. still struggling with my node setup tho.

Answer (score 1):

You can wait for another service to become available with [docker-compose-wait](https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait) project.

Add the '`docker-compose-wait`' binary to the 'test container' and run the '`docker-compose-wait`' binary before testing the API server inside the container's entrypoint.

You can give some time interval before and after checking if the service is ready.