# Dependency and shutdown of docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

A similar question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33799885/how-to-stop-all-containers-when-one-container-stops-with-docker-compose) but there has been a lot of changes to docker and docker compose since 3 years ago and I'm not sure whether it is still relevant, and to what degree.

To ask directly, if I have 3 services, ServiceA, ServiceB and ServiceC, and ServiceA `depends_on` ServiceB and ServiceC, and ServiceB and ServiceC have `restart: on-failure` but ServiceA doesn't, if ServiceA dies, will docker-compose shut down ServiceB and ServiceC?

If not, `docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit` has been suggested, but didn't work with `-d` previously. Does it work with `-d` now?