# One container is not exiting even though the other two have, in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

So I have three containers, for testing purpose:
1 dev-server
2 selenium-headless
3 unit.

They all run parallel and it works fine. The only problem is that my 1 dev-server container does not exit/stop when the other two hav exited and done running the tests. I also wants it exit with 1 if one of the other containers exit with code 1, of course.

What should I do and add for it to exit after the other two containers are exited?

My docker-compose file looks like this. :

```
version: "3"

services:
  dev-server:
    build: .
    tty: true
    hostname: yeti-ui
    container_name: yeti-ui
    ports: 
      - 127.0.0.01:8080:8080
      - 35729:35729
    environment:
      - "SKIP_DOCS=0"
      - "SCHEME=http"
      - "NODE_ENV=stage"
    entrypoint: npm
    command: run dev-server

  headless-chrome:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile-headless-chrome
    cap_add:
      - SYS_ADMIN
    network_mode: "host"

  unit-test:
    build: .
    entrypoint: npm
    command: test
```

Comment: Usually you start all services with `docker-compose up` and destroy with `docker-compose down`. Is it not working like that?

Comment: The problem here is that, when I do docker-compose up. All my three containeres will run and two of them exit while the other one is still running. I want it to automatically stop the first container to/automatically do a docker-compse stop.

Even though I add docker-compose down after docker-compose up in my makefile, the docker-compose down will never reach since the container never exits.

Comment: did you try `docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit`?

Comment: Yes. This is not working either because my dev-server container needs to wait until the other two are exited. The above command exits my dev-server container as one of the other two are exited, which means one of them will not be done running yet

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit`

Which will stop all containers if one of your containers stops. [See documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/).

Comment: Yeah, but since I have 3 containers, I want 2 of them be done before the first gets exited. This does not seem to be for that reason, right?

Answer (score 0):

I thnink your two options are:

1. Use `docker-compose run`to run the services separately and check for
   exit codes.
2. Use `docker-compose up` then parsing the output of
   `docker-compose ps`.

Check out this [Related Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29568476/1998422)

Comment: Can you please describe your answers? Im pretty new at this so I dont really know what you mean. Checking exit codes will still be the same problem as abor on container exit right? 

How do I parse the output of docker-compose?

Comment: Both approached are clarified clearly in the link. I just did not find any value in quoting it. Just have a look at the link in my answer and let me know if you need further help/clarification.

Comment: It would not be the same as `abort-on-container-exit` because you will be running each service "container" separately not in one go.