# Declarative Jenkinsfile doens't exit even if shell-script return non-zero value

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Consider this extract from my declarative syntax Jenkinsfile

```
stage("Test") {
      steps {
        sh "sh run-tests.sh"
      }
}
```

Even though the `run-tests.sh` script exit with code 1, the Jenkins job execution continues to the next step. Does anyone know what may be causing this?

EDIT: Thanks for the replies so far. I believe the problem lies elsewhere - the tests being executes are initiated by Python's `nose2` library, and if I'm not mistaking it's this command that exits with 0 regardless of the status of the tests. I'll follow that lead for now and see if that solves things.

Comment: Is there a reason you're nesting `sh`? You should be able to just do `sh "run-tests.sh"`. The first `sh` is a Jenkins pipeline function which should always fail if you have a non-zero return status, the second `sh` would depend on your operating system and configuration.

Comment: the step should be:: sh './run-tests.sh' and the shell script should be executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I'm running the tests using docker-compose, and it turns out that docker-compose return 0 regardless of what my test script return. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43367250/9475028) for more info.

I added the `--exit-code-from` option to my `docker-compose up` command, and now my CI job aborts with the same exit code as my Jenkinsfile (and thus my test script).