# How to fail gitlab pipeline from docker container?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, gitlab-ci

I run tests inside docker container on a shell runner (NodeJS/jest);

How can I fail gitlab pipeline if tests fail from inside the container?

- I've tried `process.exit(1)` in case there are failing tests but it didn't help.
- I considered running tests as part of Dockerfile `RUN` but I need the
  `environment` variables to configure URLs to other containers.

Since all tests are http calls to other containers I also expect that `after_script` will work for tearing down the environment regardless of the outcome.

Comment: Please provide your job configuration yaml.

Comment: @sytech
```yaml
e2e:
  stage: build
  tags: [high_performance]
  script:
    - docker-compose up --build e2e
  after_script:
    - docker-compose down
```

> docker-compose up --build e2e
this builds and starts the entire application and finally runs a container that executes tests

> Dockerfile looks like this
```
FROM node:14.18.1-alpine3.14

COPY <source code with tests and package.json>

CMD ["yarn", "test"]
```

Everything runs just fine, though it does not matter if container exits with status != 0 during CMD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using docker compose, you'll need to use the `--exit-code-from` to specify the service that should be used for the exit code of the `docker-compose` command.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43367250/5747944