# Test fails but GitHub workflow passes anyway

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, github-actions, cicd

I am writing a GitHub workflow to run some CI/CD pipelines.

In particular, I am running commands through a docker-compose build command. My command fails, but the workflow passes anyway. Is there an explanation for that?

Here is my yaml file:

```yaml
name: complete build
on: [pull_request, workflow_call]
jobs:
  lintage-checks:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    env:
      SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL: ${{ secrets.SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL }}
    container:
      image: lucasalt/act_base:latest # Use to get the docker-compose command
    steps:
      - uses: act10ns/slack@v2
        with:
          status: starting
          message: Pull request opened successfully by ${{ github.event.pull_request.user.login }}
        if: always()
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3 # Use to copy the files from current directory
      - name: Complexity
        run: |
          docker-compose -f scripts/docker_lintage/docker-compose.yaml up --build complexity
      
      - uses: act10ns/slack@v2
        with:
          status: ${{job.status}}
          steps: ${{toJson(steps)}}
        if: always()
```

However, when I create a pull request, what I get in github log is the following

```bash
Creating complexity ... done
Attaching to complexity
complexity       | scripts/lintage/complexity.sh
complexity       | SCORE : 1.3333333333333333 | Acceptable score : 2
complexity       | scripts/lintage/complexity.sh: line 5: bc: command not found
complexity       | Sorry, complexity score is not acceptable." 
complexity       | make: *** [Makefile:20: test_complexity] Error 1
complexity exited with code 2
```

but the workflow is considered passed as you can see from the screenshot.

[image]

If I do not build the image but simply run the bash commands, I get the failure as I expect.

Comment: The _container_ may exit 2, but apparently the `docker-compose` command you're running does not pass that to the shell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using docker-compose with CI - how to deal with exit codes and daemonized linked containers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29568352/using-docker-compose-with-ci-how-to-deal-with-exit-codes-and-daemonized-linked)

Answer (score 1):

Your workflow passes because you have [`if: always()`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#always):

> Causes the step to always execute, and returns true, even when canceled. The always expression is best used at the step level or on tasks that you expect to run even when a job is canceled. For example, you can use always to send logs even when a job is canceled.

And your docker-compose is failing because one of your containers is using `bc` which is not found/installed which explains the EXIT code 2.

If docker-compose is not exiting when that container fails, you can add `--abort-on-container-exit`, or `--exit-code-from` (see [the documentation](https://--abort-on-container-exit))

Comment: the if: always() refers to the slack step to send a report message even when the job fails.
In any case thank you, the reason why it does not fails is because docker-compose does not transfer the status to the shell, as @jonrsharpe pointed out correctly. Thanks both of you