# exec maven plugin: exit code

Tags: bash, maven, exec-maven-plugin

I am having the following plugin to run a `.sh` script:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>deploy-bundles</id>
      <phase>install</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <executable>${basedir}/deploy.sh</executable>
        <successCodes>
            <successCode>0</successCode> <-- Not working
        </successCodes>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

which copies some folders and files to certain locations. It works. However, just in case, I want to have a fail-on-error mechanism. I already have `set -e` command in my `.sh` script, but I want a maven solution too. I heard that there is a [tag](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#successCodes) called `successCodes`, I try to incorporate it. But no luck so far. Could someone point out the correct way of doing it?

**Edit:** My `.sh` script looks like this:

```
cp ../template/config.properties $component/conf
cp ../../runtime/group1/group1.mw/conf/log4j.xml $component/conf
# if the component is planning, create an additional folder called plans
if [[ $component == *".planning"* ]] 
then
mkdir -p $component/plans
    # copy all the plans here
    cp ../../mission.planning/plans/* $component/plans
fi
```

where it is expected to fail in case these folders/files are not there. So, as a test, I manually change the paths above and expect it to fail. It does fail the execution process and tells me the error (since I have `set -e` command in the `.sh` script), however maven reports is as "success".

Comment: I'm confused. You say that you have a `set -e` in your shell script, you then include the shell script, but it doesn't have a `set -e` in it. Have you missed some lines out of the shell script you have included?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not an issue with the Exec Maven Plugin, but an issue with the handling of exit codes in the Shell script.

The [`successCodes`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#successCodes) parameter is useful in situation where an executable has an exit code different than 0 for "successful execution":

> Exit codes to be resolved as successful execution for non-compliant applications (applications not returning 0 for success).

[The default behaviour](https://github.com/mojohaus/exec-maven-plugin/blob/exec-maven-plugin-1.5.0/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/exec/ExecMojo.java#L475-L489) is to consider the exit code 0 as a successful execution, and all the others as a failure,and the plugin will fail the build in that case.

In your Shell script, you have multiple commands, [each of which has its own exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90418/exit-shell-script-based-on-process-exit-code). Without any extra handling, the exit code of the script itself, as a whole, is the exit code of the last command. Therefore, even if one of the command failed (so its exit code is not zero) a successful command after that will reset the script exit code to 0. You can test that by invoking the script on the command line outside of Maven, and echo the `$?` variable, [which contains the exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312266/how-to-trap-exit-code-in-bash-script).

As such, you need to test for the exit code of each invoked command that might fail inside your Shell. (You can also use [a bit of arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357624/anding-exit-codes-in-bash) to accumulate each exit codes.)